# Separating instances in JTable with an horizontal line

Tags: java, swing, minecraft

I'm editing a open source minecraft launcher and I have a little question...
I have a JTable for various instances and I want to separate every instance with an horizontal line.
Here the JTable class:

```
public class InstanceTable extends JTable {

    public InstanceTable() {
        setShowGrid(false);
        setRowHeight(Math.max(getRowHeight() + 4, 20));
        setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
        setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void setModel(TableModel dataModel) {
        super.setModel(dataModel);
        try {
            getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(24);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And here the TableModel class:

```
public class InstanceTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final InstanceList instances;
    private final ImageIcon instanceIcon;
    private final ImageIcon customInstanceIcon;
    private final ImageIcon downloadIcon;

    public InstanceTableModel(InstanceList instances) {
        this.instances = instances;
        instanceIcon = new ImageIcon(SwingHelper.readIconImage(Launcher.class, "instance_icon.png")
                .getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        customInstanceIcon = new ImageIcon(SwingHelper.readIconImage(Launcher.class, "custom_instance_icon.png")
                .getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        downloadIcon = new ImageIcon(SwingHelper.readIconImage(Launcher.class, "download_icon.png")
                .getScaledInstance(14, 14, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    }

    public void update() {
        instances.sort();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return "";
            case 1:
                return _("launcher.modpackColumn");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return ImageIcon.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                instances.get(rowIndex).setSelected((boolean) (Boolean) value);
                break;
            case 1:
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return true;
            case 1:
                return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return instances.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Instance instance;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                instance = instances.get(rowIndex);
                if (!instance.isLocal()) {
                    return downloadIcon;
                } else if (instance.getManifestURL() != null) {
                    return instanceIcon;
                } else {
                    return customInstanceIcon;
                }
            case 1:
                instance = instances.get(rowIndex);
                return "<html>" + SwingHelper.htmlEscape(instance.getTitle()) + getAddendum(instance) + "</html>";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private String getAddendum(Instance instance) {
        if (!instance.isLocal()) {
            return " <span style=\"color: #cccccc\">" + _("launcher.notInstalledHint") + "</span>";
        } else if (!instance.isInstalled()) {
            return " <span style=\"color: red\">" + _("launcher.requiresUpdateHint") + "</span>";
        } else if (instance.isUpdatePending()) {
            return " <span style=\"color: #3758DB\">" + _("launcher.updatePendingHint") + "</span>";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean you, say have two tables on the panel, and you just want to separate them with say a [`JSeparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`I have a JTable for various istances and I want to separate every instance with an horizontal line.`*

As I understand your question, and given your code, by *instance* you mean an object (row) in your table model. Since you set `showGrid` property to `false` then no line is drawn in your table:

```
public class InstanceTable extends JTable {    
    public InstanceTable() {
        setShowGrid(false);
        ...
    }
}
```

You need to set `showHorizontalLines` property to `true` and `showVerticalLines` to `false` (if needed, actually):

```
public class InstanceTable extends JTable {    
    public InstanceTable() {
        setShowHorizontalLines(true);
        setShowVerticalLines(false);
        ...
    }
}
```

See javadoc:

- [JTable.setShowGrid(boolean
  showGrid)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowGrid%28boolean%29)
- [JTable.setShowHorizontalLines(boolean showHorizontalLines)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowHorizontalLines%28boolean%29)
- [JTable.setShowVerticalLines(boolean
  showVerticalLines)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowVerticalLines%28boolean%29)

---

> ```
> public void setShowHorizontalLines(boolean showHorizontalLines)
> ```
>
> Sets whether the table draws horizontal lines between cells. If
>   showHorizontalLines is true it does; if it is false it doesn't.

---

> ```
> public void setShowVerticalLines(boolean showVerticalLines)
> ```
>
> Sets whether the table draws vertical lines between cells. If
>   showVerticalLines is true it does; if it is false it doesn't.

Comment: +1 but this would pretty much just be a JList then :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
 jTable4.setShowHorizontalLines(true); // only HorizontalLines
      jTable4.setShowVerticalLines(true); //  only VerticalLines
      jTable4.setShowGrid(true);          // show Horizontal and Vertical
      jTable4.setGridColor(Color.yellow); // change line color
```

use this code :)